# Difference between jQuery code structures

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the difference between these jQuery code structures, or is there no difference.
Are they both an alias for `$(document).ready(function(){` and if so, why the dollar in the first code snippet?

```
jQuery(function($){
     // stuff
});
```

AND

```
$(function() {
        // stuff
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `$` parameter in the first block is unneeded in that context.

Where you would see it is in a block like this:

```
(function ($) {
    // stuff
})(jQuery);
```

In that context it would allow you to always use the `$` alias even if there was a conflicting library.

Ignoring that, there is no difference. `$` is just an alias for `jQuery`.

Both are shortcuts for `$(document).ready(function(){`

Comment: "The $ parameter in the first block is unneeded in that context." Is it ever needed, or can you always ommit it? I'm just asking cause I saw it somewhere and I never saw it like that, normally it's just jQuery(function(){

Answer (score 0):

What BNL said and yes, they are both an alias for $(document).ready(function(){

you could also write jQuery(document).ready(function(){   :)

Answer (score 0):

if you only are using jQuery then both `$` and `jQuery` is the same, but if you are using another javascript library that uses `$` as a shortcut then they wont be the same. But if its just jQuery then its just like you and @BNL have written its, its the same.

Answer (score 0):

The first code snipped serves the purpose of avoiding conflicts with other JS libraries that may be using the `$` symbol. Wrapping the jQuery code in this manner allows you to use `$` inside without worrying about conflicts. It's a good practice e.g. if you are writing a jQuery plugin to protect against conflicts in this manner. Otherwise, normally `jQuery` is a synonym for `$`.

Also have a look here for some additional info on avoiding conflicts with other libraries: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/